# Tag <li> not showing when using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was learning web scraping, and the 'li' tag is not showing when I run soup.findAll

Here's the html:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox">
<ul class="dropdown-content">
<li>
<a href=stuff</a>
</li>
</ul>
</label>
```

I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
dropdown = soup.findAll('ul', {'class':'dropdown-content'})
print(dropdown)
```

And it only shows:

```
[<ul class="dropdown-content"></ul>]
```

Any help will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in this command: `dropdown = soup.findAll('ul', {'class':'dropdown-content'})`, yo search for `ul` and `dropdown-content` class.

```
dropdown = soup.find('ul').findAll('li')
```

Comment: With these, it returns an empty list; `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Your selection per se is okay to find the `<ul>` it may do not contain any `<li>` cause I assume these elements are generated dynamically by javascript. To validate this, question should be improved and url of website should be provided.

If content is provided dynamically one approach could be to work with [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) that will render the website like a browser and could return the "full" dom.

**Note:** *In new code use `find_all()` instead of old syntax `findAll()`*

#### Example

Html in your example is broken, but your code works if any `li`s are in the `ul` in your soup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<label>
<input type="checkbox">
<ul class="dropdown-content">
<li>
<a href="stuff"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</label>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
dropdown = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'dropdown-content'})
print(dropdown)
```

#### Output

```
[<ul class="dropdown-content">
<li>
<a href="stuff"></a>
</li>
</ul>]
```